# How to load images from local folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using a [**swiper**](https://github.com/alexbrillant/react-native-deck-swiper) to display cards, where each card is an object that has an image and some data:

```
let myCards = [
    {
        name: "1", 
        image: './store/images/1.png'},
    {
        name: "2", 
        image: './store/images/2.png'},
    // ..
]

// ..

<Swiper 
    cards= {myCards}
    renderCard={(card) => {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> {card.name} </Text>
                <Image source={card.image}/> // problem here. Set source from local
            </View>
        )
    }}
</Swiper>
```

My images are `.png` and are in a folder inside the app directory: `MyProject/app/store/images`

The above pops an error saying *invalid prop 'source' supplied to Image*

And if I follow [Image-Facebook Code](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html) and do this: `source={require(card.image)}`, it errors: *anything passed to `require` should be string literal*

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `require` the images into the array:

```
let myCards = [
    {
        name: "1", 
        image: require('./store/images/1.png')},
    {
        name: "2", 
        image: require('./store/images/2.png')},
    // ..
]
```

then, your code should work as it is:

```
<Swiper 
    cards= {myCards}
    renderCard={(card) => {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text> {card.name} </Text>
                <Image source={card.image}/> // problem here. Set source from local
            </View>
        )
    }}
</Swiper>
```

react-native doesn't allow you to dynamically require images AFAIK.

Comment: Hi and thanks. Quick question, how can I set the image width to be the parent's width? like to "fill" the whole parenting container, I know how to do it in all languages except react native ios thing

Comment: look at flex box layout, there are several options.  you can use `justify-content: stretch` to fill the width. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/